# Is the Fourier series independent from the basis used in its calculation?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $\{u_n\}_{n \in \mathcal{N}}$  be an orthonormal base of an Hilbert space $H$. For every funcion $f \in H$ we define the $n$-th Fourier coefficient as $$\hat f (n) := (f, u_n)_H$$ and we define the Fourier series of $f$ as
\begin{equation} Sf(x) := \sum_{n \in \mathcal{N}} \hat f (n) \ u_n. \end{equation}

My question is: while I was working with $L^2[0,1]$ I have encounthered different basis of this space but noone has never showed me that the Fourier series obtained for every basis was the same. (Since the calculations could be very long I have not tried to evaluate the Fourier series of the same function using two different basis)

In other words:

> Is the Fourier series independent from the basis used in its calculation according to the formula written above?

Comment: Two Fourier series representations of the same function are equal in $L^2$.  That shoud be straightforward for you to show.  HINT:  The triangle inequality should be useful.

Comment: I can't get it. Does this applies to all Hilbert spaces? Can you give me more details please?

Comment: Are the sets of bases complete?  If so what does this mean with respect to $L^2$ convergence?

Comment: Okay, I think that since $L^2$ is an Hilbert space we have that $\|f - Sf\|_2 = 0$ and this is seen as the convergence of the partial sums as $n$ goes to infinity. Am I right?
But then there is another question: we commonly extend the definition of $\hat f (n)$ also for functions $f \in L^1$ and this is commonly done using the esponential base. What happens to $Sf$ if we define it using another base? I mean, I do not know any theorem that "reproduces" the result above for the $L^1$ space.